# SharedPreferences not working/saving data from EditText field

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am using shared preferences but my code is not working. I don't know what's wrong with it. Am I implementing something wrong?

My main java activity(relevant bit of code) is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String s;
    public static final String subjectKey = "SubjectID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(subjectKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    TextView calc_monday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monday_calc);


    calc_monday.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){



                    CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(MainActivity.this);
                    cdd.show();
                    TextView text1 = (TextView) cdd.findViewById(R.id.Subject_ID);

                    String text = sharedPreferences.getString(subjectKey, " ");


                    if(text != " ")
                    {
                       text1.setText(text); /* Edit the value here*/
                    }

                    TextView text2 = (TextView) cdd.findViewById(R.id.Room_ID);
                    text2.setText("6 (SEECS)");
                    TextView text3 = (TextView) cdd.findViewById(R.id.Time_ID);
                    text3.setText("09:00am  - 09:50am");


                }
            }
    );

    calc_monday.setOnLongClickListener(
            new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    SettingDialogClass SDC = new SettingDialogClass(MainActivity.this);
                    SDC.show();

                    EditText texii = (EditText) SDC.findViewById(R.id.set_Subject_ID);






                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(subjectKey, texii.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();


                    return true;


                }
            }
    );
```

Basically I want that when I longClick a textbox (calc_monday), a dialog box should appear which appears. Now I should be able to write something on the EditText field which appears on this dialog box. Whatever I write should be stored and then displayed when I SINGLE CLICK on the same textbox (calc_monday)

Please see the 2 methods: onClick and onLongClick to understand.

The code is not working, i.e the text I write on EditText field on onLongCLick dialog box is not being displayed when I single click on the textbox.

What's wrong with the code

Comment: use editor.commit() if your need to access the data soon after committing it.  editor.apply() takes a little longer to commit

Comment: @Jasz I did that. Still same result. The textbox displayed at single click is blank

Comment: @FahadSaleem you should not compare string data using == or !=, so it may be a part of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you long press calc_monday, it just show your custom dialog with **empty** value for EditText. To save your text when input in EditText, create a button in your custom dialog, and call onClickListener action for this button, then save value to SharePreferences.

```
calc_monday.setOnLongClickListener(
        new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                SettingDialogClass SDC = new SettingDialogClass(MainActivity.this);

                EditText texii = (EditText) SDC.findViewById(R.id.set_Subject_ID);

                Button btnSave = (Button)SDC.findViewById(R.id.your_custom_button);
                btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(subjectKey, texii.getText().toString());
                        editor.apply();
                        SDC.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                SDC.show();

                return true;
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: SDC and texii are accessed from within class. So I declared SDC to be final and cut the texii statement and put it inside onClick(View v) function.

But on long click, application has stopped working

Answer (score 0):

I think it's should be :

```
String text = sharedPreferences.getString("Name", " ");
```

Comment: I did the change. But now when I single click, nothing is being displayed i.e the textbox is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods for saving and loading Strings with preferences:

```
//save prefs
public void savePrefs(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

//get prefs
public String loadPrefs(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String data = sharedPreferences.getString(key, value);
    return data;
}
```

You can call the load method like this:

```
subjectKey = loadPrefs("YouCanNameThisAnything", subjectKey);
```

And you can call the save method like this:

```
savePrefs("YouCanNameThisAnything", subjectKey);
```

More details on how to use shared preferences is also available in the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show me how to use load and save method  using the keys and value i provided in my question? I don't understand how exactly I can use your methods

Comment: Hello Fahad, the method declarations stay the same.  I edited the examples for calling the methods, so that the examples use your subjectKey String variable.  You can use anything for the key name in quotes when calling the methods, just be sure to USE THE SAME NAME every time, if you want to access/save the subjectKey value.

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle your load function is not really clear, it should only need a key and be able to return. if you used the second param for the default then you should not use subjectKey. You will confuse the OP

Comment: @meda do you know the answer? Please write it if you know

Comment: Actually these are the exact methods I have been using in all my apps successfully.  The second parameter for the load function comes into play as fall back in case there isn't anything stored at that key name.

Answer (score 0):

```
//create and initialize the intance of shared preference
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Session", MODE_PRIVATE);


//save a string
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
edit.putString(subjectKey , texii.getText().toString());
edit.commit();


//retrieve the string
String subject = sharedPreferences.getString(subjectKey, "");
```

Comment: @FahadSaleem to me it sounds like a text box issue try loggin

Comment: logging is not giving any value of textbox. This is the code I am using

`EditText texii = (EditText) SDC.findViewById(R.id.set_Subject_ID);
                        s = texii.getText().toString();

                        Log.d("fluffylol",s );`

Comment: I used another EditText field (Name) and the logcat shows the value always remains "name" which is the predefined value of the EditText. It never changes even though I click on the box and write something else instead of "name". What do I do?

Comment: See the logs proves the issue is with the editText, I would say to ditch this custom class, and move the code to listener directly